# Understanding Do While Loop with nested if else statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, computer-science, do-while

My professor made us do this in class and I am super confused looking at those outputs. 
Does this`(x + " " + y + " " + z)` mean add all 3 variables `if (y > z)` ? The output doesn't make any sense to me at all.

```
public class Practice
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {

            int x=10, y=11, z=3;
            do
            {
                System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
                if (y > z)
                {
                    y = y-5;
                }
                else
                {
                    y = y + 3;
                }
                x = x - 2;
            } while (x > 0);
            System.out.println("Bye");
        }
    }
```

```
OUTPUT:
10 11 3
8 6 3
6 1 3
4 4 3
2 -1 3
Bye
```

Comment: Pay attention in your class and read your books

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here.  You can _see_ what that line is doing - it's printing the numbers, with spaces in between them all.  So it's not really _adding_ - it's _concatenating_.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh thanks for encouraging words. Just here to get outside help with highly talented individuals.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem ahh! I was little confused with the + sign. Just started to Learn Java, this is one of my first java program.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that Java uses the same symbol for adding numbers as it does for concatenating text.  In simple terms, if a `+` sign has something that isn't a number, on either side, it will concatenate text instead of adding numerically.  There's one exception, (`char` values) which you'll meet later.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem it’s little confusing when you’re new to this subject but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
```

This is not adding x,y and z. Its just appending values in string for printing
your numbers are converted to strings

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.  It’s basically adding strings “ “ or spaces.

Comment: here + means string concat and not add from math

Comment: haha thank you I was trying to hard to understand why there was plus in between. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome mate, have been throughg this ohase long back, I recommend you to see what is operator overloading in java

Comment: Also please do not forget to accept answer if it answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers